# Read specific line from .csv file in C

Tags: c, csv, parsing

I have a CSV file (`.csv` extension) like this:

```
"id_product","name","brand","category","price"
0157,Sparachiodi,Mannesmann,FaiDaTe,32.99
0211,Cavi di rame,Chapuis,FaiDaTe,20.23
4815,Tenaglia,Ks Tools,FaiDaTe,7.50
8451,Lucchetto,Blinky,FaiDaTe,4.55
```

My question is: How can I write some C code that reads the file from only the second line? The thing that I want to do is a sort of research in the file. (For example, I want to search the product with the name "cavi", and I will show the whole line.)

Comment: "How can i read from file only the second line" - Open the file in a text editor and read the second line?

Comment: By reading and *ignoring* the first line? You *do* know how to read a single line, don't you?

Comment: Yes, in a text editor is easy, but in c how  can i scanf only one specific line ?

Comment: By using `fgets`. You cannot read a *particular line* from a text file, you must read them *sequentially*.

Comment: We are neither a consulting, nor a tutoring or coding service. What you ask is a standard lesson in every C book. i'd recommend reading one or asking your teacher.

Answer (score 1):

You have a csv file. You know that legitimate lines are short (<1000 characters)

So

```
 char buff[1024];
 fgets(buff, 1024, fp); /* read line 1 */
 fgets(buff, 1024, fp); /* read line 2, overwriting line 1 */
```

but probably what you want is this

```
 char buff[1024];
 fgets(buff, 1024, fp);
 /* check buff is a legitimate csv header here */

 /* after we've got rid of the reader, do data lines until they run out */
 while(gets(buff, 1024, fp))
 {
    char *field = strtok(buff, ',');
    if(field)
    {
        /* numerical field, product id */
    }
    field = strtok(0, ',');
    if(field)
    {
         /* product name field */
    } 
 }
```